# How to stream music in C# with PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am trying to recreate some features of **Spotify** in **C#** using the **PostgreSQL database**.

The reason is simple, I want to gain more knowledge, and I think this is a good challenge.

But I ran into an obstacle that I've been standing for days. Spotify he doesn't download the music, he does her **streaming**, plays the music while it's downloaded.

However, I can't do this in C#, I'm using the **PostgreSQL** database.
I'm well locked in this part, I tried several implementations, but I think I'm not on the right track, and on the internet I imagine I'm looking wrong, otherwise I would have found it.

Do you have any guidance for this **streaming process in C#**? I've tried to read the **large_object bytes from PostgreSQL**, but couldn't.

Any suggestions or guides about the process are welcome.

Comment: This question is too broad and lacks the necessary [mcve]. Take a look at the [help] and especially [ask].

Comment: Streaming is quite different from download. You should first dive into and research streaming (audio streaming) in general. How to provide the data to be streamed should come second. Not finding anything hints me to that you actually don't know what to look for. Maybe try drop "PostgreSQL" out of your searches. Have a look into RTSP/RTP protocols if they fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will research yes. It already gave me a good insight, in the sense that I was thinking that the processing was by the database, and now I realized that is not quite, thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You start by getting the file into the database or its network location into the database, whichever gives you better performance; Then start with creating an implementation of a bytestream. You want to be transmitting raw data to c#.

you then build a real time interpreter that takes in using your file format, one byte at a time, and plays the value associated with that section. does that make sense? this is simple to do with many libraries and the brunt of it is just figuring those out.

You seem like you've PROBABLY got that first part down, and are instead having issues with the database. A lot of things we did at my last company involved saving file network locations and indexing files on disk. You might be able to instead point your streamer to a file locally using a server, and instead transmit data from one point to another in that manner instead.

You seem more than capable of doing this just judging by your speech. I hope this comment was helpful, and if it was not I apologize as well. I would be interested in seeing your finished result.

for clarification here would be that workflow:

1. request for a song listed in table dbo.Songs
2. matches that song onto dbo.songlocation
3. streams from dbo.songlocation.location from the filename dbo.songlocation.songname = dbo.song.name and verified directory returns true
4. enjoyment of that music

Comment: Thank you so much friend, I will take a look at the subject and see how this process works. Actually I was researching quite wrong, I did a brief research here with what I was told, and I already had a good sign of the way I should go. As soon as I have functional results, I want to post the git link here for a look

Comment: Avoid the semantics complaints, this is absolutely the approach I'd suggest having experience with image transmission and audio transmission over servers.You seem like you don't want me to do the work for you so I won't help you in that regard.